# How to unmarshal Pulumi auto.Result object struct or map

Tags: go, pulumi

I'm deploying servers to Hetzner using Pulumi's automation API in Go, but can't figure out how to get the resulting connection information out of the deployment result.

Here's the truncated code:

```golang
import (
    ...

    "github.com/pulumi/pulumi-command/sdk/go/command/remote"
    "github.com/pulumi/pulumi/sdk/v3/go/auto"
    "github.com/pulumi/pulumi/sdk/v3/go/pulumi"
)

...

deployFunc := func(ctx *pulumi.Context) error {
        // Create SSH key pair, upload them to Hetzner, get back a `*hcloud.SshKey`
        ...
        
        // `server` is a *hcloud.Server object
        server, _ := DeployServerToHetzner(ctx, sshKey)

        // This is the info I want to retrieve from the result
        connectInfo := remote.ConnectionArgs{
            Host:       server.Ipv4Address,
            Port:       pulumi.Float64(22),
            User:       pulumi.String("root"),
            PrivateKey: sshKeyPair.Private,
        }

        ctx.Export("server-connect-info", connectInfo)

        return nil
    }

stack, _ := auto.UpsertStackInlineSource(ctx, stackName, projectName, deployFunc, opts...)

res, _ := stack.Up(ctx)

// This is a string but I need it as either map or struct
serverConnectInfo := fmt.Sprintf("%v", res.Outputs["server-connect-info"].Value)
```

I'm able to retrieve the result from `res.Outputs`, but it's a string. I know the server deployment and response with connection details are successful because when I log `serverConnectInfo`, it looks like this:

```
serverConnectInfo map[host:123.456.789.10 port:22 privateKey:-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
b3BlbnNza...
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
user:root]
```

Based on a few dubious solutions online, I tried marshalling it as we would a JSON and then unmarshalling it into a Pulumi `remote.ConnectionArgs` instance. That obviously didn't work, because the struct looks like this:

```golang
// From https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/pulumi/pulumi-command/sdk@v0.7.2/go/command/remote#ConnectionArgs

type ConnectionArgs struct {
    ...
    Host pulumi.StringInput `pulumi:"host"`
    Port pulumi.Float64PtrInput `pulumi:"port"`
    PrivateKey pulumi.StringPtrInput `pulumi:"privateKey"`
    User pulumi.StringPtrInput `pulumi:"user"`
}
```

I'm thinking of constructing my own struct and then retrying the JSON unmarshalling and marshalling solution but it seems like if the `ConnectionArgs` struct already has `pulumi` tags, there should be some kind of `pulumi.Unmarshal` method somewhere. Am I wrong? I couldn't find it anyway.

I've looked into the docs too but haven't seen anything that helps. Maybe I missed a page?

Comment: `res.Outputs["server-connect-info"].Value` is a map. It only becomes a string if you run it through fmt.Sprintf. Value has type `interface{}`, so you have to type assert it to access the map. Try something like `res.Outputs["server-connect-info"].Value.(map[string]interface{})["host"].(string)` (guessing the types here).

Comment: @Peter You're absolutely right. I ran it through `fmt.Sprintf`. My mistake. It works perfectly with your solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Peter pointed out in a comment, `res.Outputs["server-connect-info"].Value` is a map and correctly guessed that I ran it through `fmt.Sprintf`. That was just silly of me.

This works:

```golang
serverConnectInfo := res.Outputs["server-connect-info"].Value.(map[string]interface{})
```

Works well in a Go test using the built-in testing package too:

```golang
assert.NotEmpty(t, serverConnectInfo["host"])
assert.Equal(t, serverConnectInfo["user"], "root")
```